# how to show List inside a table using App script

Tags: javascript, function, web, google-apps-script

I am having problem with list inside the table
I am selecting the Table using getSelection() method

I am trying to insert everything I select inside a inside a new doc file

I am selecting Table which contains image,list paragraphs.

It is working fine but the only problem is that is not showing the List style(bullet,square).
And also to Show the image Inside the table
Paragraph and Texts are working fine

What can help me so that I can render everything I select

```
function copySelectionToNewDoc(selection, targetDoc) {
  var body = targetDoc.getBody();
  var fg=0;
  selection.getRangeElements()
    .map(function (element) { return element.getElement() })
    .forEach(function (element) {
      var type = element.getType();
        // Logger.log(type);
        // Logger.log(element.getAttributes());
        // Logger.log(element.getParent().getAttributes());
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        var check=element.copy();
        Logger.log(check);
        body.appendParagraph(element.copy());
        Logger.log("i am paragraph");
      }
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) {
        var txt=element.getParent();
        Logger.log(txt);
        body.appendParagraph(txt.copy());
        Logger.log("i am text");
        Logger.log(txt.getText());
        // var text = body.editAsText();
        // Logger.log(text);
        // text.appendText(txt.getText());
        // Logger.log(text.getParent());
      }
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
        var dstTable = body.appendTable(element.copy());
        var srcTable = element.copy().asTable();
        Logger.log("i am table");
      }
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
        var txtGlyphType = element.getGlyphType();
        body.appendListItem(element.copy()).setGlyphType(txtGlyphType);
        console.log(body);
        console.log("i am item");
      }
      else if(type==DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_CELL&&fg==0){
        Logger.log("i am table cell");
        var tt=element.getParentTable();
        var ele=tt.copy();
        Logger.log(tt.getType());
        var dstTable = body.appendTable(ele);
        var srcTable = tt.asTable();
        fg=1;
      }
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_ROW&&fg==0) {
        var tt=element.getParentTable();
        var ele=tt.copy();
        Logger.log(tt.getType());
        var dstTable = body.appendTable(ele);
        var srcTable = tt.asTable();
        fg=1;
        Logger.log("i am table row");
      }
      else if(type==DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE){
        var img=element.getParent();
        body.appendParagraph(img.copy());
        Logger.log("i am inline image");
      }
    });
  targetDoc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function createAndLoadTable() {
  const vs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById('docid');
  let body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendTable(vs);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

My active range data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 17 | 4 | 8 | 0 | 1 | 16 | 11 | 0 |
| 14 | 7 | 9 | 1 | 16 | 8 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 18 | 15 | 7 | 14 | 16 | 0 | 3 | 19 | 5 |
| 9 | 10 | 19 | 17 | 13 | 2 | 14 | 12 | 5 |
| 12 | 16 | 5 | 18 | 13 | 6 | 16 | 12 | 16 |
| 8 | 12 | 9 | 17 | 14 | 7 | 10 | 12 | 18 |
| 14 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 15 | 5 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 3 | 18 | 14 | 6 | 15 | 16 | 2 |
| 14 | 4 | 7 | 2 | 11 | 19 | 18 | 17 | 1 |

Document:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response but this is working fine can you insert table inside a table and image inside the table listitem inside the table and return it as the document this is what i  am looking for. Thanks again